# Load images on demand in a ViewFlipper

Tags: android, viewflipper

I'm using a ViewFlipper with automatic flipping and animation to display the number of images a user wants, however this can cause out of memory error. How can I load the images on demand (load only 2 images and each time the ViewFlipper flips, I load one more and discard the first one)?

Comment: What have you done so far ? Please post some code with logcat error.

Comment: I just loop through a collection of image URIs, adding a new ImageView for each of them. If the user filled the collection with 20 images, I add 20 ImageView widgets to the ViewFlipper at once.